# PDFView scrolls the fields out when trying to fill pdf-form. (annotations)

Tags: ios, pdfview

I'm using PDFView in order to let users fill PDF Forms. Whenever the user touch a field in the document, the cursor appears in the field and he can enter text. That's ok. But the problem is that the PDFView scrolls the document chaotically and the fields gets out of the view. Sometimes, even if the user scrolls the doc to the correct position, it scrolls out again whenever he uses the keyboard. It's really weird.

Here is my very simple code where I create the PDFView and set the doc:

```
let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
    
// Fit content in PDFView.
pdfView.autoScales = true

pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: fileURL)
self.pdfView = pdfView
```

Why does it happen. Can it be a fault in the pdf form format?